# Why can't I bind my directive's Inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, reactjs

I am trying to learn about Angular directives and how to incorporate React.JS components into Angular, by taking [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router) UI Router example, and put all of the original templates into directives. What should happen is when you type in the input boxes in the middle, and the results are mirrored in the div below. 
I am having trouble passing information around with isolated scope. I am trying to pass the data object using '=' in isolated scope.

The name input is using the same name that I set up in the isolated scope but it gives me "

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive
>   'profile' is non-assignable!

" when I try typing in the name input. The [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/nonassign) mention this problem, and I thought I had set it up in a similar way but it hasn't fixed anything.

The email input goes right for formData.email, where formData is the name of the object set up in my controller. In this case I think I am bypassing the isolated scope(which I don't think I want to do) and there is no binding. I can write something in this input but it is not reflected below.

What part am I missing? I suppose one way to fix it would be with a watch in the link function, but I don't know how that would send the input in the directive to the div outside of it.

My code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jd008LI4HVed67QWDNDI?p=preview) at Plunker

Comment: I voted to close it because it's unlikely someone will benefit from this (unless the question is rewritten to be something else).  Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer to my problem was the underscore. I had set my values with names like form_name and form_email. Old Python habit. It turns out Angular doesn't like underscores so much, I removed them and sure enough Name started worked. Email broke but now I know how to fix that.